# Onclick Cancel application event

Tags: javascript

new to js...need your help. I want to create a cancel button that cancels an online form session when the cancel button is clicked. Before cancelling the session, I want a notification popup to appear (onclick event) asking for the user's confirmation before cancelling the application session. See code below:

```
 <form>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Product">Product</label>
       <input type="text" name="product" id="product" required="required" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Product">Product1</label>
       <input type="text" name="product1" id="product1" required="required" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Product">Product2</label>
       <input type="text" name="product2" id="product2" required="required" value="">
   </div>
  <div>
  <button name="submit">Add Product</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="">**Cancel**</a>           
  </div>


 </form>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to put the canceling code? When the user clicks submit and then pop up the confirm/cancel option? Because if not, you can just provide a "reset" button so that all the fields in the form become empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need on click confirm function which will ask user approve before continue

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="confirmCancel()">**Cancel**</a>
<script>
    function confirmCancel () {
        var message = "Are you sure?";
        if (confirm(message)) {
            // do what you want
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <form id='form1'> 
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="Product">Product</label> <input type="text" name="product" id="product" required="required" value=""> </div> 
<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="Product">Product1</label> <input type="text" name="product1" id="product1" required="required" value=""> </div>
 <div class="form-group"> <label for="Product">Product2</label> <input type="text" name="product2" id="product2" required="required" value=""> </div>
 <div> 
<button name="submit">Add Product</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="reset('form1')">**Cancel**</a> </div> 
</form>
    <script>
    function(id){
       if(confirm("do you want to cancel?")){
           $("#"+id)[0].reset();
        }
    }
    </script

>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without editing the form select the element, attach an 'click' event listener to the element you want to listen in on, in this case, "cancel" a tag. Once the click is registered confirm using a confirm box. if Ok grab the form and reset it and redirect the user. Else, do something else.

```js
// grab your cancel anchor tag
var anchor = document.querySelector("[href='http://www.google.com']");
// grab your form
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
// add an event listener on to your cancle anchor tag
anchor.addEventListener('click',clicked =>{ 
// assign your confirm to varable yes
var yes = confirm('are you sure you want to cancle');
if(yes===true){
// if they confirm their departure reset the form 
form.reset();
//alert them of a successfull form reset and inform them of the reroute
alert('the form has been reset you are going to be rerouted to google');
// use location to reroute to a different domain
//window.location.href("http://www.google.com")
// or within the current domain using a relative path
// window.location.href = '../' one level up
// winsow.location.href = '/path' relative to a domain
}else{
alert('you decided to cancle');  
// do nothing 
}
});
```

```html
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Product">Product</label>
       <input type="text" name="product" id="product" required="required" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Product">Product1</label>
       <input type="text" name="product1" id="product1" required="required" value="">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Product">Product2</label>
       <input type="text" name="product2" id="product2" required="required" value="">
   </div>
  <div>
  <button name="submit">Add Product</span></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="">**Cancel**</a>           
  </div>
 </form>
```